# How to share(facebook or twitter) a page in AngularJS depend of the route?

Tags: angularjs, routes, share, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with sharing a page in AngularJS, when I click to "Facebook Share button", just took the Open Graph of the home, but not the data of the page that I am.

Please help me =)

Comment: Please add relevant code, need to see whats going on. Are you using ngRoute or ui.router?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what component are you using now, but this one seems quite easy to use and understand, with examples included:
https://github.com/djds4rce/angular-socialshare

Comment: But, are you used that ever? Because I used that and don't work to me.

Comment: Can you post a code sample? This way it should be easier to figure out what you're doing wrong.